# Cropping a pdf using Ghostscript make it rotate 90 degrees

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I use gs9.21 to crop a [PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlsosiw04eqqd3f/source.pdf?dl=0), and when this file contains rotated text, gs automatically rotates the entire page. Is this a bug? Can i avoid it?
the gs command:

`gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o croped.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=2125.9834 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1502.36646 -c "<</PageOffset [-14.1733 -28.3464]>> setpagedevice" -f source.pdf`

when del the rotated text or convert the pdf outlines, everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly; Ghostscript (more specifically the pdfwrite device) does not 'crop' PDF file. It also doesn't compress them or optimise them or anything else.

What it does is create a brand new PDF file, whose content (a the PDF syntax level) is more or less totally different to the input file. This **is** documented [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#Overview)

As to why the output is rotated that is documented in the Distiller Parameters [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#PDFWRITE). Look for the `AUtoRotatePages` control.

Comment: thanks.The problem has been solved.GS is powerful and there has too many control parameters for me.

Comment: May be i find a bug.
use gs2.3,when convert a pdf to outlines with -dNoOutputFonts param,the pdf cannot pass HP rip.
The error:
`Rip: hp-pro:3
ioerror; OffendingCommand: Do(PDF); File: %console% `
gs9.21 is OK.

Comment: I suppose the first question would be 'why are you doing that ?' It will only make the output PDF file bigger and the output poorer quality. Can you open the PDF file with a different reader (ie Acrobat) ? If so then it sounds more like the printer is faulty. In any event, the place to report a bug is the Ghostscript Bugzilla tracker. Don't forget to supply the command line and an example file to reproduce the problem. Oh, also Do is an image (or Form) operator, so not really anything to do with text or outlines.